# RPC not working on addclose handler

Tags: gwt, rpc

I'm facing a weird problem in GWT. I generate an excel file on server side for users to download. But after the download the file should get deleted. 
I have put logic to delete it on server-Side on 2 occasions. One when user logs out and another when browser is closed. 
When the user logs out, it works perfectly as it has enough time to make a call to the server whereas in case of addclosehandler, it loses connection and file remains as it is.
i.e. the method on server side does not get executed.

I tried to find another way to call the method directly by importing the package and inheriting in gwt.xml. But an error was thrown at the compile time and rightly so that server side cant be inherited.

Please get me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some browser cancel all pending requests while closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

> But after the download the file should get deleted. I have put logic
>   to delete it on server-Side on 2 occasions.

This does not have to do anything with the client. I don't know excactly how your progam works but generally it should work like this:

- Client makes a request
- Servlet generates the bytes (Is there really a need to store the bytes in a file?)
- sends them to client

And that's it.

Comment: No, I just couldn't achieve it but i found another way to include native javascript code in project and its working porperly.